# VSCode is unable to connect to my WSL2 distribution

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, vscode-remote

For some reason, my vscode is unable to connect to WSL. I am using Debian and it is running on WSL2. Every time it tries to connect, the connection gets timed out.

This is error log

```
log.ts:417  INFO Invoking resolveAuthority(wsl)...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,1)][0ms] obtaining proxy...
log.ts:417  INFO Started local extension host with pid 13520.
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,1)][619ms] invoking...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,1)][1138ms] returned WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)
log.ts:417  INFO resolveAuthority(wsl) returned 'WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)' after 1138 ms
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-c328b16e-5ddb-4024-9b09-3c2ce21eec5e)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-783c5459-fc5c-4a31-bd60-62e7b7312659)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-c328b16e-5ddb-4024-9b09-3c2ce21eec5e) was successful after 146 ms.
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-783c5459-fc5c-4a31-bd60-62e7b7312659) was successful after 254 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][Management   ][c328b…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 1] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Invoking resolveAuthority(wsl)...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,2)][0ms] obtaining proxy...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,2)][1ms] invoking...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,2)][2ms] returned WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)
log.ts:417  INFO resolveAuthority(wsl) returned 'WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)' after 2 ms
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-ac0b3553-66a4-4231-af6b-90ac6dee8d22)...
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][783c5…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 1] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-9c07e418-7167-44a5-ac03-f2e47e4ba0a7)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-ac0b3553-66a4-4231-af6b-90ac6dee8d22) was successful after 98 ms.
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-9c07e418-7167-44a5-ac03-f2e47e4ba0a7) was successful after 121 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][Management   ][ac0b3…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 2] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Invoking resolveAuthority(wsl)...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,3)][0ms] obtaining proxy...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,3)][0ms] invoking...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,3)][2ms] returned WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)
log.ts:417  INFO resolveAuthority(wsl) returned 'WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)' after 2 ms
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-d1cf3ca6-dcee-4dd1-8242-1124ba140f69)...
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][9c07e…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 2] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-6d8382a4-bf22-4e12-b96a-ad1b1fb99de7)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-d1cf3ca6-dcee-4dd1-8242-1124ba140f69) was successful after 96 ms.
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-6d8382a4-bf22-4e12-b96a-ad1b1fb99de7) was successful after 118 ms.
extensionDescriptionRegistry.ts:369 The customer named _initialize has been holding on to the lock for 30s. This might be a problem.
(anonymous) @ extensionDescriptionRegistry.ts:369
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][Management   ][d1cf3…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 3] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Invoking resolveAuthority(wsl)...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,4)][0ms] obtaining proxy...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,4)][1ms] invoking...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,4)][3ms] returned WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)
log.ts:417  INFO resolveAuthority(wsl) returned 'WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)' after 3 ms
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-4ef56539-2bfd-4d79-9134-85b9a4c7db63)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-4ef56539-2bfd-4d79-9134-85b9a4c7db63) was successful after 96 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][6d838…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 3] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-f8057a40-e307-4209-955a-8e60bef15ae7)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-f8057a40-e307-4209-955a-8e60bef15ae7) was successful after 163 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][Management   ][4ef56…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 4] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Invoking resolveAuthority(wsl)...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,5)][0ms] obtaining proxy...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,5)][1ms] invoking...
log.ts:417  INFO [LocalProcess0][resolveAuthority(wsl,5)][2ms] returned WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)
log.ts:417  INFO resolveAuthority(wsl) returned 'WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)' after 3 ms
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-646b82fc-400d-4be7-98de-5d1a1c0f951f)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-Management-646b82fc-400d-4be7-98de-5d1a1c0f951f) was successful after 93 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][f8057…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 4] An error occurred in initial connection! Will retry... Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-1478c627-e3c2-4c68-8ad5-99f77fca4cb2)...
log.ts:417  INFO Creating a socket (renderer-ExtensionHost-1478c627-e3c2-4c68-8ad5-99f77fca4cb2) was successful after 111 ms.
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][Management   ][646b8…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 5]  An error occurred in initial connection! It will be treated as a permanent error. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR Cannot register remote filesystem provider. Error while fetching remote environment. Time limit reached
notificationsAlerts.ts:42 Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Time limit reached)
c @ notificationsAlerts.ts:42
(anonymous) @ notificationsAlerts.ts:28
y @ event.ts:1127
z @ event.ts:1138
fire @ event.ts:1162
addNotification @ notifications.ts:228
notify @ notificationService.ts:253
prompt @ notificationService.ts:331
(anonymous) @ remoteAgentService.ts:68
4log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
notificationsAlerts.ts:42 Could not fetch remote environment
c @ notificationsAlerts.ts:42
(anonymous) @ notificationsAlerts.ts:28
y @ event.ts:1127
z @ event.ts:1138
fire @ event.ts:1162
addNotification @ notifications.ts:228
notify @ notificationService.ts:253
Ob @ nativeExtensionService.ts:408
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: vue
log.ts:437   ERR Time limit reached: Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11483)
    at o.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11464)
    at a.value (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11316)
    at o.y (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1902)
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:2119)
    at T.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10243)
    at I.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10653)
    at a.value (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11055)
    at o.y (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1902)
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:2119)
    at T.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10243)
    at I.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10653)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:10816
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][ExtensionHost][1478c…][initial][WebSocket(127.0.0.1:5017)] the handshake timed out. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR [remote-connection][attempt 5]  An error occurred in initial connection! It will be treated as a permanent error. Error:
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
log.ts:437   ERR Error received from starting extension host (kind: Remote)
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] vscode-custom-css is active!
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Application directory e:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Main HTML file e:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-sandbox\workbench\workbench.html
log.ts:437   ERR Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (remoteAgentConnection.ts:148:20)
    at o.h (remoteAgentConnection.ts:144:28)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:126:86)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at a.value (remoteAgentConnection.ts:99:41)
    at o.y (event.ts:1127:13)
    at o.fire (event.ts:1158:9)
    at T.cancel (cancellation.ts:69:19)
    at I.cancel (cancellation.ts:124:16)
    at remoteAgentConnection.ts:89:26
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] [vscode-icons] v12.7.0 activated!
log.ts:437   ERR Time limit reached: Error: Time limit reached
    at o.i (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11483)
    at o.h (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11464)
    at a.value (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11316)
    at o.y (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1902)
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:2119)
    at T.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10243)
    at I.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10653)
    at a.value (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:11055)
    at o.y (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:1902)
    at o.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:2119)
    at T.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10243)
    at I.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:87:10653)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:688:10816
```

I also have docker installed and connected to WSL. Earlier docker was automatically set to the default distribution which caused some mounting errors but changing the default distribution fixed that. However this hasn't resolved the issue of vscode being unable to connect. I have also tried using different distributions such as Ubuntu and Fedora but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might get fixed with.

1. Install VS code for windows not for linux ([VS code download](https://code.visualstudio.com/download))
2. Install [Remove Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)
3. Open your Terminal (best will be to download Terminal from [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-US&gl=US))
4. Open the Project directory and type `code .`
5. The terminal will automatically install and Open VS code link with WSL.

For more information, Look at the docs [Get Started with VS Code with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode)